# Groupby by keeping all character columns intact

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a data frame looks like,

```
    chrom   ID          Name         Sample
0   22  26920140.0  CTA15             PE12
1   22  41830075.0  CTA15             PE14
2   10  134596540.0 RP11.3           AE29
5   12  117142987.0 RP11.2         AE30
6   14  50793639.0  RP11.4          AE31
```

All I need is to count the number of occurrence of `Name` within the data farme, also I need to keep others columns. And so I tried as,

```
   df['count']= df.groupby('gene', as_index=True).agg(len)

  chrom start   Name Samples
    gene                                                                                
    CTA15   2   1.0 1.0 1
    RP11.3  1   1.0 1.0 1
```

I dont see the value of my row but just numbers, Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['count']= df.groupby('Name')['Name'].transform(len)
print (df)
   chrom           ID    Name Sample  count
0     22   26920140.0   CTA15   PE12      2
1     22   41830075.0   CTA15   PE14      2
2     10  134596540.0  RP11.3   AE29      1
5     12  117142987.0  RP11.2   AE30      1
6     14   50793639.0  RP11.4   AE31      1
```

---

```
df['count']= df.groupby('Name')['Name'].transform('size')
print (df)
   chrom           ID    Name Sample  count
0     22   26920140.0   CTA15   PE12      2
1     22   41830075.0   CTA15   PE14      2
2     10  134596540.0  RP11.3   AE29      1
5     12  117142987.0  RP11.2   AE30      1
6     14   50793639.0  RP11.4   AE31      1
```